# CSS for Display Suite Fields not applied

Tags: panels, display-suite

**I'm attempting to place text next to the top of images inline for a content type using CSS on fields through Display Suite with a built-in layout in Panels (Two column bricks)**

I am using a subtheme for the professional_theme.

- I have tested and ensured the style sheet is over-ridden to my subtheme
- I have inserted the css shown below (and tried several other css codes)
- I have inserted the css names into the CSS Classes of Display Suite
- I tried applying the styles to several different fields as well as
  the region independently and together.

That all being said I think there is extra CSS code being inserted that is throwing off the style being pulled in but I have no idea where it is coming from.

**The code below displays Source Code with the CSS style I applied to the image and a text field:**
The names of the only styles I applied are: **.floatleft .floatright**

```
<div id="block-system-main" class="block block-system">


<div class="content">
<div class="panel-display panel-2col-bricks clearfix" >
<div class="panel-panel panel-col-top">
<div class="inside"><div class="field field-name-title field-type-ds field-label-hidden">
<div class="field-items"><div class="field-item even"><h2>Are you the Kind to be Kind</h2></div></div></div><div class="field field-name-field-date-good-news field-type-datetime field-label-hidden">

<div class="field-items"><div class="field-item even"><span class="date-display-single">Tuesday, October 27, 2015 - 09:30</span></div></div></div>
<div class="field field-name-field-image-positive-news .floatright"><img src=".../sites/default/files/styles/medium/public/positivenews/476950.jpg?itok=uIGCBUH2" width="220" height="165" alt="" /></div>
<div class="field field-name-field-inspirational-thought-oday field-type-text-long field-label-hidden .floatleft"><div class="field-items"><div class="field-item even"><p>You are in charge of your own destiny, don’t try to control theirs.</p>
</div></div></div></div>
</div>
```

**CSS CODE:** Keep in mind that I have tried other CSS codes

```
.floatleft {
clear: both;
vertical-align: top;
float: left;
padding: 4px 10px 4px 0;
}

.floatright {
clear: both;
vertical-align: top;
float: right;
padding: 4px 0 4px 10px;
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated. I tried finding CSS documentation for Display Suite with little luck.
WO

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, remove the `.` from your classes in your HTML code, e.g. you should have `<div class="floatright">` and not `<div class=".floatright">`.

If you want to have one element next to another by using `float`, your combined element's width should be smaller than their container's. And since both your image and the text are inside divs and a `div` has 100% width by default, you have to specify a smaller width to each.

```
.floatleft {
    float: left;
    width: 40%;
}

.floatright {
    float: right;
    width: 30%;
}
```

Just change the widths accordingly.

Comment: Wow, I figured the problem was going to be something simple but not as simple as removing a period. Thank you so very much Typologist!

Comment: Cool! I'm glad it worked :)